# How to make a custom tableView cell accessory

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have not yet found any really good examples on how to do this. There is an image that I want to use as the accessory button and when I put it in and click on it doesn't work. So it looks correct but doesn't work...
Here is my code:

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]
    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableView_Green_Disclosure.png"]];
```

So how do I get my UIImageView to call `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` whenever it is tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the blog post hdr->cmdline for creating custom accessory view for `UITableView`.
The author used `UIButton` objects with images for custom accessory view.

Comment: any link to this post? :)

Comment: PFB the link ..http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/

Answer (score 6):

A thorough reading of `accessoryView` and `accessoryType` would reveal that they are mutually exclusive ways to customize a cell.

Setting the `accessoryType` will cause the table view delegate method to be called when it is tapped.

Setting the `accessoryView` will ignore the setting of `accessoryType` and give you something to display.  If you want to receive a callback from the custom view you've put in place, it should be a control that is wired up to do so. (Or any view with a gesture recognizer.)

If you use a button, and set its action to `accessoryTapped:`, you will receive the button as the "sender" argument.  You can walk up the view hierarchy until you find a table view cell, and then ask your table view what the indexPath of that cell is.  This will then get you an index into your model objects and you be able to act on it appropriately.

Alternate to the button, you can enable interaction on the UIImageView above, and add a gesture recognizer to it.

Comment: Thank you for the through answer.

Answer (score 2):

To make the button actually do something, you'll need to implement `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` from UITableViewDelegate.

When an accessory button is tapped in a row, this method will be called and you'll have the chance to act appropriately using the passed in index path to determine which row's accessory was tapped.

Comment: Thank you but how do I implement that for the imageview I just made, I guess I just assumed that since I specified the accessory type that it would call that method?

Answer (score 0):

To make use of the accessoryView - you would need to set the cell's accessoryType to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone deposit a UIButton (with associated image) into the cell and then wire it up to receive user touches.  You might use something like the code below as the IBAction response to the cell's UIButton being touched:

```
- (IBAction) accessoryButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
NSUInteger pathInts[] = { 0,0 };
pathInts[1] = self.currentselectedrow; // ivar set when tableview row last selected
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:pathInts length:2];
[self tableView:mytableview accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

The UIButton would be wired to execute this glue code by way of a line inside your tableview's "cellForRowAtIndexPath:" function

```
[thecell setButtonTarget:self  action:@selector(accessoryButtonPressed:)];
```

One thing I noticed is that the UIButton seems to want a 'swipe right' versus a simple 'tap' touch in order to trigger the event - but it could be my beta iOS that's the problem. Note that I had added a UIButton* object named 'cell_accessoryButton' to the Custom Cell source.

In the cell's source you'd support the 'setButtonTarget' call with code like this:

```
- (void) setButtonTarget:(MyViewController*)inTarget action:(SEL) inAction
{
[self.cell_accessoryButton addTarget: inTarget
                      action: (SEL) inAction
            forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

It's so much easier to just use the accessoryType reference and let iOS do the heavy lifting - but, if you want a custom graphic, etc - this is another path that works.